# Postgres - Removing milliseconds from timestamp text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In my database we have a column that holds data in XML format. And one of the XML elements holds dates that looks like this:

```
<timestamp>2013-05-22 16:01:26.78 CDT</timestamp>
<timestamp>2013-05-15 10:29:44.588 CDT</timestamp>
<timestamp>2013-02-27 09:37:54.677 CST</timestamp>
```

So I extracted the value between `<timestamp>` using:

```
substring(table.column from '<timestamp>(.*)</timestamp>') as "Time Stamp"
```

But I'm having a hard time trying to use regular expression to remove just the milliseconds.

What I want is `2013-02-27 09:37:54 CST`

I don't know enough regular expressions to filter out the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing query, you could cast the result (note the `TIMESTAMPTZ(0)`):

```
SELECT substring(col1,'<timestamp>(.*)</timestamp>')::TIMESTAMPTZ(0) as "Time Stamp"
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work. I've tried the TIMESTAMPTZ and it won't include the CDT/CST time zone. It only converted the time stamp to my current time zone. For example 2013-05-22 16:01:26.78 CDT becomes 2013-05-22 14:01:26.78 CDT after I cast it.

Comment: Eh? That's what TIMESTAMPTZ does -- it uses your current `timezone` setting for display. Was your question that you *only* wanted the milliseconds? Or do you mean you want the TIMESTAMP displayed in *only* the CDT/CST tz of the data in the table?

Comment: Oh man I'm so sorry! I wrote my question incorrectly. I meant I wanted to remove the milliseconds.

Comment: The solution I posted above using "TIMESTAMPTZ(0)" removes the milliseconds. Your comment above suggests that you don't want the results in your current time zone -- if that's the case, change your client timezone before running the query by issuing `SET timezone TO 'UTC';` or whatever tz you want the results in. You could also cast the results of that query to TEXT if you wanted it to not change with whatever timezone your client application is set to.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't just using:

```
/<timestamp>[^\.]*.([^\s]*)\s.*<\/timestamp>/
```

do it? that's ruby regex, btw.

What you want is "<\timestamp>", "any non-period chars", ".", "any nonwhitespace", "a space", "anything", "</timestamp>"

**with "any non-whitespace" selected**. (in parens in ruby)

Hope that helps. Dunno how much the regexes vary. some like ruby and perl are identical.
Note I have escaped some chars - SO doesn't like the timestamp tag.